# Perl, dynamically include package

Tags: perl, dynamic, module

Let's say I have a perl module file and I want to include and use it dynamically at runtime. Said module includes a class that I need to instantiate without knowing its name  until runtime.

For example,

```
#inside module.pm

package module;

sub new {
#setup object
}

#inside main.pl

#get module.pm as argument
my $module_var = #load reference to module using text argument?
my $module_instance = $module_var->new();
```

Comment: A better more modern idea would make a base class, and factor off these dynamically loaded entities as `MooseX::Traits`, then you just instantiate the baseclass with said traits `BaseClass->with_traits('Foobar::Baz')->new;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done without eval as follows:

```
my $module_name = 'Some::Module';

(my $require_name = $module_name . ".pm") =~ s{::}{/}g;

require $require_name;

my $obj = $module_name->new();
```

If you need to do this many times, just wrap up that code in a subroutine:

```
sub load_module {
    for (@_) {
        (my $file = "$_.pm") =~ s{::}{/}g;
        require $file;
    }
}

load_module 'Some::Module', 'Another::Module';
```

Answer (score 7):

```
my $module_var = 'module';
eval "use $module_var; 1" or die $@;
my $module_instance = $module_var->new();
```

Note that the `eval` is a possible security hole.  If `$module_var` contains code, it will get executed.  One way around this is to use [Class::MOP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::MOP#Utility_functions).  Replace the `eval` line with:

```
use Class::MOP;
Class::MOP::load_class($module_var);
```

If you don't want to require Class::MOP, you could copy the `_is_valid_class_name` function from it into your code, and just make sure that `$module_var` contains a valid class before you `eval` it.  (Note that if you're using [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose), you're already using Class::MOP behind-the-scenes.)

Comment: is there a safer way than eval? security is a concern for me

Comment: `Class::MOP::load_class()` being deprecated, it's possible to find [the same utility in `Class::Load`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Load).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `eval`.

```
my $module = "Foo";
eval "use $module;1" or die($@); # Couldn't load module
```