# Syntax for using variable in package name?

Tags: perl

I want to call a method on a package name generated from a variable. I think I've done this before but it appears I have forgotten how. Here's the broken version of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
my $var = 'Page';
my $p = My::Package::$var->new();
```

Comment: You *reallý* don't want to do this.

Comment: Why? What is the issue with it?

Comment: Take a look at the duplicate question, and read [*Why it's stupid to "use a variable as a variable name"*](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) especially Part II.

Comment: I just read them and they don't seem to apply to my situation. Thanks, though.

Comment: It's less critical when you're using class names, but it's best not to split a class name up into bits, which are mostly a reflection of their file structure on disk. You can write `my $class = 'My::Package::Page'` and `my $p = $class->new`. (You can even write `my $var = 'Page'` and `my $p = "My::Package::$var"->new` but that's horrible.) But now you have an object `$p` whose methods you don't know without checking its class.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working using answer at [Perl, dynamically include package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470706/perl-dynamically-include-package)

```
my $module_name = 'Some::Module';
(my $require_name = $module_name . ".pm") =~ s{::}{/}g;
require $require_name;
my $obj = $module_name->new();
```

Comment: This answer doesn't match the question! But since you claim it's a duplicate of the other question, I'll oblige and close your question.